# Can't access files in SMB share

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, samba

I'm trying to mount some share from my synology NAS via SMB. I'm using Linux Mint and when I mount it over the GUI ("Computer"->"Network"->"NAS"->"Sharename") everything works fine.

But I want it to mount at boot, so i studied several tutorials.
I got it to mount the share at startup under some folders in my home but I can't access any of the files or folders. I don't have permissions (somehow). 
When I create a file I immediately lose all permissions on it.

```
//192.168.1.254/pyload  /home/username/mount/NAS/pyload  cifs  credentials=/home/tim/.smbcredentials,guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

"dirty" workaround like `chmod 777 ./*` didn't work

Comment: What error you are getting while typing `mount -a` ?

Comment: `mount -a` returns the message that only root can do it. `sudo mount -a` runs without any errors.